# Graph Theory: Finding the number of trails from one vertex to another

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[image]

How many trails are there from $a$ to $c$?

The answer is that there is $4 + 4!$ trails. I don't understand the $4!$ part. Please help me understand how to solve similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

A "trail" appears to allow vertices to be visited more than once, so the $4!$ counts the number of ways you can go from $a$ to $b$, then *back* to $a$ along a *different* edge, then back to $b$ along yet another different edge, and then on to $c$.

Answer (score 0):

I need to pick odd number of edges to get from $a$ to $b$.

If I pick one edge, I have $4$ options.

If I pick three edges:

First I have $4$ options to pick one edge to be omitted. $(4)$

Then I can choose the ordering of the three edges. $(3!)$

Hence $$3!(4)+4=4!+4$$